# Cant sort using object datasource

Tags: c#, objectdatasource

i am using a objectdatasource to populate my grid
when i select the page where the grid is, it enters on the methods select and selectcount,  but when sorting it gives me column not found.
what is it strange is that i have a breakpoint on the method select and if i try to sort by a fiedl the parameter sSortColumn should have the column id, and it should enter the breakpoint but it doesnt.

this is my grid and objectdatasource

```
 <ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGridAutAssiduidade" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
    Height="99%"  DataKeyFields="ID" DataSourceID="odsAutAssiduidade" >
     <EmptyRowsTemplate>
        Sem registos...</EmptyRowsTemplate>        
    <Columns>     
        <ig:TemplateDataField Key="chkBox" Width="40px">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAll" CssClass="center" OnClick="SelectAll(this)" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" CssClass="center" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </ig:TemplateDataField>
        <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="ID" Hidden="false" Key="ID">
            <Header Text="ID" />
        </ig:BoundDataField>  
        </Columns>   
    <behaviors>
     <ig:Sorting>
        </ig:Sorting>
        <ig:EditingCore>
        </ig:EditingCore>
        <ig:ColumnResizing>
        </ig:ColumnResizing>

        <ig:Paging PagerMode="NumericFirstLast" PageSize="20" QuickPages="5">
        </ig:Paging>
        <ig:RowSelectors RowNumbering="True">
        </ig:RowSelectors>
    </behaviors>
    </ig:WebDataGrid>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsAutAssiduidade" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" SelectCountMethod="GetAsAutAssiduidadeCount"
    SelectMethod="GetAsAutAssiduidade" TypeName="IdOntime.AsAutorizacoesAssiduidade" SortParameterName="sSortType"
    EnableCaching="True" EnableViewState="True" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex" MaximumRowsParameterName="maxRows">
    <selectparameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="sSortType" Type="String" />
</selectparameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

and here is the methods

```
 public DataTable GetAsAutAssiduidade(String sSortType, int maxRows, int startRowIndex)
    {
        return new DataTable();//testing -
    }

    public int GetAsAutAssiduidadeCount(String sSortType)
    {
        return NRows;

    }
```

what i am doing wrong?
i am using a infragistics component called webdatagrid, and i allow sorting by adding  in the behaviors.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work for me with the regular `<asp:GridView />`. As for why breakpoint isn't hit - you enable caching in object data source. Disable it so your breakpoint will trigger:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ...
   EnableCaching="false" ... />
```

Be aware that by default the grid isn't sorted so `sSortType` can be one of: `""`, `"ID"`, `"ID DESC"`.

Comment: one more thing in our case the first click on a column does the sort value change or does it maintain. what is hapening in mine is that the after loading the grid i choose a column to sort and then click it. the parameter is empty, then i click it again an the parameter is "field" then if i click it again it says "field desc". the problem is the first click is stating that the sort column is "" when it should be "field desc".. is it a problem on the component?

Comment: @HugoSilva - for me it is first empty, then field, then field desc.  I would check how you set default sort column (if you do that) or try to set it explicitly. I won't be a great resource on that as I don't have experience with your grid component.

Comment: ok, i was just trying to see if the execution was the same..thanks for the help.